# Why make pointers static in dialog procs?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I'm going through many examples of basic win32 dialog procedures. They seem to take this basic pattern.

```
class Person
{
     char Name[63];
     int Age;
};

BOOL CALLBACK EditDlgProc ( HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
     static Person* person;
     switch(uMsg)
     {
     case WM_INITDIALOG:
         person = (Person*)lParam;
         return FALSE;
     case WM_COMMAND:
           .....
     }
     return FALSE;
}
```

I want to know why make person *static*?

- Is this for efficiency? (avoid assigning person to lParam every call)
- Is this for sharing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is to maintain state of the pointer `person` between calls to the function `EditDlgProc()` .

It ensures that:

- The pointer is created only once during the lifetime of the program.
- It maintains state of the pointer across consecutive calls to the function and
- Gets destroyed only once when the program ends.

> **Is this for efficiency?**

Yes, Possibly. Difficult to say without knowing the design considerations.

> **Is this for sharing?**

No.
Note that the scope of an `static` variable is limited to the function in this case, So it cannot be shared as such.

Comment: Note also that using a static means that you can have only one copy of the dialog at a time.